# Why does my PrintWriter fail to work in ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, process, inputstream, outputstream

I'm trying to take over another application from java side.

Take over here means to get the output of another application and input the command to it.

The code I have used:

```
public class ProcessTest implements Runnable{

    BufferedReader reader;
    PrintWriter writer;
    Thread readThread;
    boolean terminate = false;

    public ProcessTest(){
        try{
            initialize();
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
    }

    public void initialize() throws Exception{
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("another_application.exe");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = builder.start();

        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);


        reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        writer = new PrintWriter(osw);  
        readThread = new Thread(this);
        readThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(terminate == false){
            int c;
            try {
                c = reader.read();
                if(c == -1){
                    return; 
                }
                System.out.println(c);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void input(String str){
        writer.write(str);
        writer.println();
        writer.flush();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ProcessTest obj = new ProcessTest();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            String str = scan.nextLine();
            obj.input(str);
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

At the beginning, I can use `writer` to input command to application and use `reader` to get its output.

Both `reader` and `writer` work fine before I enter a particular command.

After I enter a command to it(The effect of the command: 1, Change the application's status from configuration to running; 2, Plenty of output). The `reader` keeps working but not the `writer`. The application fails to show any response from writer's input.

I'm at my wits' end, please kindly tell me the **possible reason** why such issue happens. The application I'm trying to take over is company internal application so I haven't give you its name.

Comment: the `input` method is never called

Comment: @ScaryWombat See the update

Comment: What happens when you try to write? Is there an exception?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks. I will edit the question. Not working here means the applicaiton doesn't show any response to my input. But it will show response if I input it from its native CLI.

Comment: @mm759. No exception. The application just do nothing like I haven't sent the command to it.

Comment: You do realize that your output will just print numbers on screen, rather than the normal program output, right?

Comment: @RealSkeptic. Yes, it's just for debug usage here.

Comment: Can you make sure that it does not have to do with line endings (\n vs. \r\n)? I currently don't see a problem, but to make sure. According to Javadoc Scanner.nextLine does not include the line ending and PrintWriter.println uses the system specific line ending. Another possible problem is the encoding. Can you debug what is passed to input?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I can get the output of another_application.exe all the time though the reader thread. What issue I'm faced with now is that the another_application.exe fails to respond to my input. It responds to my input firstly but go on strike after I send a specific command to it. The specific command will change its status from configuration to running and will have plenty of output at the same time

Comment: So add this information to your question. It's not clear from the way you wrote your question that it *does* respond to commands at first except *this* particular command.

Comment: @mm759 Thanks, but it doesn't make sense since the writer works fine before the specific command is sent to it.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks, I will modify it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see a reason for the problem. Debugging might help. And if it's not completely sure if the output of the process still works when the input does not work any more it might be worth investigating the output. The process could wait as long as it's output is not delivered.